# MVC3 AJAX Form - DateTime Overflow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

In my application I have an Index page with a list of **Documents**. I want to add a new Document  with an AJAX form on that same Index page. I am passing a **NewDocument** object to the Index page using a ViewModel.

The AJAX Form (I omitted some parts for readability):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index_AddDocument", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "MainList" }))

<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewDocument.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewDocument.Date)
</div>
```

And here is the method that should save the new **Document** to the database, and update the Partial View list of documents:

```
public ActionResult Index_AddDocument(HomeIndexViewModel viewModel)
    {

        db.Documents.Add(viewModel.NewDocument);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return PartialView("ListOfDocs", db.Documents);
    }
```

This doesn't work, I'm getting an exception at `db.SaveChanges()`. It says:

> InnerException    {"An overflow occurred while converting to datetime."}  System.Exception {System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException}

EDIT:
My Document domain model has the following Date property:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

In the AJAX form I just type a random date like 5/2/2005 and then click Submit, and then get the exception mentioned above.

Comment: how does your domain model looks like ? Are you setting the value of any DateTime Properties ?

Comment: Could you do a `Debug.Write(viewModel.Date);` at the beginning of your `Index_AddDocument` action and tell us what it says?  Whenever I've seen this issue, it typically ends up being something strange - like the DateTime value being passed as null.

Comment: Ok, I added the Debug line, and entered a date of '2/5/2010' in the field. This is the output:

2/5/2010 12:00:00 AM A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.DLL

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `viewModel.NewDocument.Date` prior to the `db.SaveChanges()` call?

C# can handle dates from 1st Jan 0000 to 31st Dec 9999.  I know SQL Server can't handle that whole range (e.g. SQL Server 2008 can't handle before 1/1/1753 i believe)

I suspect that SQL Server CE also has limits on its date range and is balking at the default 1/1/0000 DateTime value.

Comment: I just put a random date in the Textbox like 5/2/2005 and click Submit.

Here is the model property Date:

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

Comment: OK.  So the date should be acceptable - can you do anything to check the date is being passed correctly into `Index_AddDocument`? If you can't debug or print out something, try throwing an exception yourself to see - e.g. `throw new Exception("Date is" + viewModel.NewDocument.Date)`.  Are there any other Dates in your model?

Comment: I added a Debug Write in the action method, and entered a date of '2/5/2010' in the field. This is the Debug output: 2/5/2010 12:00:00 AM A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.DLL

Answer (score 1):

I think I just solved my own problem. The 'Date' column in my database is of the type 'datetime'. But my domain model had this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

I changed that DataType to 'DataType.DateTime' and now it seems to be working fine.

Thanks everyone for the guidance!